# Bitmap graph drawing, how do you add thickness to a line?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, graphics, graph, bitmap

The following function will draw a Sine wave by setting the pixels on a bitmap. But how would you draw the line thicker? without resorting to the Graphics API.

```
function drawWave(amp:int, freq:int):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < stage.stageWidth; i++)
    {
        var ang:Number = 2 * Math.PI * freq * i/stage.stageWidth;
        bmd.setPixel(i, yaxis - amp * Math.sin(ang), 0xff0000);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: draw the line into a Shape object using graphics.lineTo etc (with a width of your choice). then copy the entire graph by using bitmapData.draw(shape)

Answer (score 2):

Try this - adjust lineWidth as required:

```
function drawWave(amp:int, freq:int):void
{
    var lineWidth:Number = 10;
    var shape:Shape = new Shape();
    var g:Graphics = shape.graphics;
    g.lineStyle(lineWidth, 0xFF0000);
    for (var i:int = 0; i < stage.stageWidth; i++)
    {
        var ang:Number = 2 * Math.PI * freq * i/stage.stageWidth;
        var ypos:Number = yaxis - amp * Math.sin(ang);
        if (i==0)
            g.moveTo(i, ypos);
        else
            g.lineTo(i, ypos);
    }
    bmd.draw(shape);
}
```

Draws graph to a Shape object rather than a BitmapData - so you can take advantage of the anti-aliasing it provides. Then copy the whole thing to the BitmapData.

See [docs for lineStyle(..)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineStyle%28%29) for more options on tweaking line appearance

Edit:

If you insist on using only BitmapData, you could try this:

```
 bmd.drawRect(new Rectangle(i-WIDTH*0.5, yaxis-amp*Math.sin(ang)-HEIGHT*0.5, WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0xff0000);
```

Replacing WIDTH and HEIGHT as required, it will draw rectangles rather than single pixels - giving a thicker line, but not very pretty i imagine

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about Graphics API, however I think I would like to stay away from the Graphics API, as a learning exercise, and also to allow me to port the code more easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the line to be thicker, I would suggest using a BitmapData of a circle an instead of using setPixel, use draw().

Of course you'll need to offset the draw location of the circle, based on the size of the circle. - width/2 and -height/2